# libxml2.2.dylib reference in python program

Tags: python, path, libxml2

A python library that I'm using uses libxml2.2.dylib.  I'm getting this error message:

Reason:

```
Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

My system's version of `libxml2.2.dylib` is older and is in `/usr/lib/`.  I downloaded the newest version of libxml2.2.dylib using homebrew, and that is in `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib/`.

I would like my Python application to use that version instead of the one the system uses.

Is this a matter of adding the homebrew folder to the path?

Answer (score 5):

Try to follow the instructions [here](http://lxml.de/build.html#building-lxml-on-macos-x) to build lxml with static dependencies. This way you don't have to worry about which version of `libxml2` or `libxslt` it is linked against.

It could boil down to

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install -U lxml
```

Comment: I tried this and just wound up throwing a new lxml-related ImportError, i.e.: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/[me]/.envs/[virtualenv]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _lzma_auto_decoder

Comment: did you create your virtualenv _before_ installing a static version of lxml in the system Pyhon ? in that case I suspect the venv to have imported the problem upon creation

Comment: interestingly this resolves another issue: /lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0