# Scrapy Incompatible library version

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, libxml2

I am trying to get Scrapy going on my macbook however, after pip install Scrapy and getting everything done, when I import it it gives me the error

```
ImportError: 
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib


Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

What should I do to fix it so I can finally get started learning Scrapy?? :(

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486145/libxml2-2-dylib-reference-in-python-program

Comment: You can also try [Miniconda on OS X](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html#os-x-miniconda-install), then, [`conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda).

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172384/lxml-runtime-error-reason-incompatible-library-version-etree-so-requires-vers